# Excel - move a whole row into the next worksheet if the text in a particular cell of the first worksheet is Y (or Yes)

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, excel-formula

I am trying to set up a formula where worksheet 1 is a list of dates, names and the final column (I) is a simple Y or N (for Yes or No).

If the answer is Y (or Yes) then I would like the entire row to be copied into the next worksheet (worksheet 2) and if the answer is N (or No) then it does not go onto the next worksheet.

Is this possible to do, and if so how can i do it by cell formula (I don't want to change the srcipt module if possible)?

Any guidance would be gratfeully recieved.

Answer (score 1):

Moving is a 2-step process in Excel (i.e. cut - paste) so this can't be done with a formula.

You could look into

1. autofilter to display all Y-records within the base data worksheet ... you then can copy/paste them manually
2. advanced filters to display and even copy Y-records, but within the same worksheet
3. writing a VBA procedure (not a function) to do the extraction job for you, where you first would set the Y/N field in each record manually, then press a button which moves the records; you gould go as far as capturing the event of entering Y into column 3 to automatically fire the move procedure, but I wouldn't recommend it ... what if the user accidentally entered Y ...
4. finally you could insert on the extraction sheet an array formula to display the Y-records; example:

Sheet 1

```
      A       B      C
1  Index    Info   Flag
2      1       A      Y
3      2       B      N
4      3       C      N
5      4       D      Y
```

Sheet 2

- copy headers of sheet 1 into A1..A3
- select B1..B3 and enter formula `=IF(Sheet1!C2="Y",Sheet1!A2:C2)`
- press Ctrl+Shift+ENTER to save as array formula
- copy B1..B3 down

not very nice though, because you will get a FALSE FALSE FALSE for every N-record

Personally I would prefer 3) ... the button solution

Comment: +1 pretty extensive answer. I'd just add that you can use advanced filters (#2) from another sheet, but you need defined names for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a workaround.

Create another tab or table within the original worksheet that pulls all your rows over via a conditional. This can be done with a VLOOKUP nested within an IF statement. (IF the cell = YES, VLOOKUP the rest of the row). I apologize for not including the exact formula, but its pretty easy to find videos etc on that portion.

On your other worksheet, use PowerQuery to query the original worksheet, and append the rows from your new table.

Answer (score 0):

simply put = sign where u wanna see the result than go to that entire row and drag cursor to downward press enter. that's it.
regard: that's T.J

Answer (score 0):

i entry some data i.e Customer name in Sheet1;s A1 cell , and I use this name in sheet2's cell B1 using this formula =Sheet1!B1 , now I want to move(transfer as CUT ) data from sheet2;B1 to sheet3's "C1" cel , from which formula it can be possible , ples tell

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest solution but it does work and I use it at my job on a workbook for logging checks received. It carries over the row if the check is postdated so that the row appears at the top of the next sheet. And it's an array formula so all the data is contiguous.

Let's use MikeD's data example above and expand upon it:

```
      A       B      C            D                  E
1  Index    Info   Flag        Index 2             Info 2
2     1       A      Y    =If(C2="Y",A2,"")  =If(C2="Y",B2,"")
3     2       B      N    =If(C3="Y",A3,"")  =If(C3="Y",B3,"")
4     3       C      N    =If(C4="Y",A4,"")  =If(C4="Y",B4,"")
5     4       D      Y    =If(C5="Y",A5,"")  =If(C5="Y",B5,"")
```

Basically you are adding columns to the right of your data which checks to see if Column C equals "Y" and copies the row one cell at a time. So what we end up with is:

```
      A       B      C      D        E
1  Index    Info   Flag  Index 2  Info 2
2     1       A      Y      1        A
3     2       B      N    
4     3       C      N    
5     4       D      Y      4        D
```

Then on Sheet2 in cell A1 enter the following Array Formula (don't forget to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5<>"",ROW(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Then in cell B1 you would enter a similar Array Formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5<>"",ROW(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Then you can highlight A1:B1 and drag the formulas down to A1:B5 and you should see this:

```
 Index 2  Info 2
    1       A
    4       D
```

Then you can go back to Sheet1 and hide those nasty looking formula columns :).